# How can I use a boolean to toggle an images visibility?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use a single button to toggle between an image being visible and invisible. I want the first click to make the image appear, and the second to hide it again. I figured using a boolean would be the best way to do this, but I can't quite get it to work.

```js
function myStats(){ 
counter = true;
    if(counter == true){ 
        document.getElementById('stat').style.display = 'block';
    }
 if(counter == false){
     document.getElementById('stat').style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
body{background-color: #A9A9A9;}
</style> 
</head>
<body>
<p> Dallas Fuel </p>

<center><img id="stat" src="Images/buttonLA.png" style="display:none;"/></center>
<button onclick="myStats()">Player 1</button>
<h3 id="var"></h3>
</body>
</html>
```

I realize this will obviously not work because I'm not toggling the boolean, but that's what I'm looking for help with.

Comment: you are resetting counter each time `myStats` is called.

Comment: Read the code out loud.  Click, execute myStats. In myStats it sets counter to true and than I check to see if counter is true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a css class called `hidden`, then use [classList.toggle()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/classList). When the button is clicked toggle the class on the image.

It can be done like this:

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', myStats)

function myStats() {
  document.getElementById('stat').classList.toggle('hidden')
}
```

```css
.hidden { display: none; }
```

```html
<center><button>Player 1</button></center>
<center><img id="stat" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" class="hidden"></center>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: What would I change if I only wanted this to happen when a specific button is clicked?

Comment: you would change `querySelector('button')` to a specific button, such as `querySelector('button.my-class')` or `querySelector('button#my-id')`

Answer (score 0):

I edited your snippet to put a toggle on there and made it so the function `myStats()` doesn't set `counter = true` everytime you click it.  Seems to work fine.  I also hoisted the declaration of the counter variable above that function declaration, since that's where your toggle should be, represented by `counter = !counter`.

```js
let counter = true;
function myStats(){ 
counter = !counter;

    if(counter == true){ 
        document.getElementById('stat').style.display = 'block';
    }
 if(counter == false){
     document.getElementById('stat').style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
body{background-color: #A9A9A9;}
</style> 
</head>
<body>
<p> Dallas Fuel </p>

<center><img id="stat" src="Images/buttonLA.png" style="display:none;"/></center>
<button onclick="myStats()">Player 1</button>
<h3 id="var"></h3>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Boolean variable should be outside of the function so its value won't reset every time you called a function. Also you should toggle this boolean variable value from true to false and vise versa. Check out my solution. Hope this helps!

```js
var isImageShouldBeVisible = true;

function toggleImageVisibility() {
  isImageShouldBeVisible = !isImageShouldBeVisible;
  
  if (isImageShouldBeVisible) {  
    document.getElementById('stat').style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    document.getElementById('stat').style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
body{background-color: #A9A9A9;}
</style> 
</head>
<body>
<p> Dallas Fuel </p>

<center><img id="stat" src="Images/buttonLA.png" style="display:block;"/></center>
<button onclick="toggleImageVisibility()">Player 1</button>
<h3 id="var"></h3>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because `counter` remains same throughout the code. You need to add `counter = !counter` at end of you function.
 I would do it using ternary operators. There is need of `Boolean` just check the `style.display`

```js
let elm = document.getElementById('stat');
function myStats(){ 
  let {display} = elm.style;
  elm.style.display = display === 'none' ? 'block' : 'none';
}
```

```css
body{background-color: #A9A9A9;}
```

```html
<p> Dallas Fuel </p>

<center><img id="stat" src="Images/buttonLA.png" style="display:none;"/></center>
<button onclick="myStats()">Player 1</button>
<h3 id="var"></h3>
```